# Unable to uninstall postgreSQL from Add/Remove Programs

Tags: postgresql

Running Windows XP Pro. Have been successfully using and deploying postgres for 2 years.

When I try to Uninstall PostgreSQL 8.3 using Windows Add/Remove Programs I get this message:

Service "PostgreSQL Database Server 8.3' (pgsql-8.3) failed to start. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services.

I have tried the following:

Created and logged on as various users as members of Administrators group.
Deleted the 'postgres' user (is this a problem?)
Removed all references to postgres in the registry. Rebooted
Removed the PostgreSQL Service from the service list. (sc delete pgsql-8.3)
Deleted the whole Postgres 8.3 directory in Program Files.

I have worked on this for 6 hours today to no avail. GRRRR.

Desperate for some suggestions??

Comment: You deleted (almost) everything (user, registry, directory, files, etc) and now you want to uninstall something that is not there anymore? What's the current problem you're trying to solve? You deleted PostgreSQL without the uninstallerer, it's now gone.

Answer (score 1):

Install PostgreSQL again in the same directory with all options. It will repair your installation. Then you'll be able to uninstall it using "Add/Remove Programs" cleanly.

Comment: No it wont reinstall (says "Can't Start the Service")
Ended up solving this by manually reinstalling and registering the pgsql service again from the command prompt THEN I was able to uninstall and reinstall as normal.
Thanks for bothering to reply.